# Why am I not able to fetch database field values in a class using Jooq's into method?

Tags: java, javabeans, jooq

This is my methood with the Jooq query:

```
private List<UserEmailOrganisation> getEmailsAndOrgNames() {

    Result<Record2<String, String>> r = dsl
    .fetch(dsl
            .select(I_USERS.EMAIL_ID, I_ORGANISATIONS.NAME)
            .from(I_USERS)
            .leftOuterJoin(I_ORGANISATIONS)
            .on(I_USERS.ORGANISATION_ID.equal(I_ORGANISATIONS.ID))
            .where(DSL.timestampAdd(I_USERS.UPDATED, MINIMUM_INACTIVE_DATE,
                    DatePart.DAY).lessOrEqual(DSL.currentTimestamp())));

    logger.debug(r.toString());



    return r.into(UserEmailOrganisation.class);
}
```

logger.debug method prints -

```
|email_id                           |name            |
+-----------------------------------+----------------+
|email1@some.com              |org1            |
|email2@some.com              |org2            |
```

So my query **is** returning some results. So I think the issue is not with the query but the into method.

This is my UserEmailOrganisation class

```
public class UserEmailOrganisation {


    public String emailId;

    public String name;

    public UserEmailOrganisation(String emailId, String name) { 
        this.emailId = emailId; 
        this.name = name; 
    }

}
```

From the JOOQ docs 
http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.x/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html

> If no default constructor is available, but at least one "matching" constructor is available, that one is used.
>
> A "matching" constructor is one with exactly as many arguments as this record holds fields
>   When several "matching" constructors are found, the first one is chosen (as reported by Class.getDeclaredConstructors()
>   When invoking the "matching" constructor, values are converted onto constructor argument types.

So my code should work right? As it has a matching constructor. But it doesn't. I get the following exception.

```
org.jooq.exception.MappingException: No matching constructor found on type class com.kubera.insights.admin.jobs.BackOfficeUsersReminderJob$UserEmailOrganisation for record org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper@2ccd7880
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper.init(DefaultRecordMapper.java:321)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper.<init>(DefaultRecordMapper.java:257)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper.<init>(DefaultRecordMapper.java:244)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapperProvider.provide(DefaultRecordMapperProvider.java:81)
at org.jooq.impl.ResultImpl.into(ResultImpl.java:1499)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was I was using an inner class to hold the table values.

That is not possible according to issue -
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1821

Moving the class **UserEmailOrganisation** outside solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it returning a null result?  Can you dump the SQL text of this query, and then run it against the I_USERS table to see if you get a result?  You might need to add another constructor to handle a null result.

```
public class UserEmailOrganisation {

    public String emailId;

    public String name;

    public UserEmailOrganisation(String emailId, String name) { 
        this.emailId = emailId; 
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public UserEmailOrganisation(Object response) {
        if (response == null) {
            // what happens if it's empty?
        }
    }
}
```